# Powershell script Fixing the output of ConvertTo-Html

Tags: html, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have one CSV file with values. I need to display my CSV file as an HTML report. In my CSV file mentioned the execution report link as a value under column status. I need to display that particular report cell value as a link in my report too. I tried the below code but it changed all my values under the status column as a link.

Csv file

```
Name                 Date               Status
Execution starts    Dec-20               Pass
Comparing           Dec-20               Fail
Report              Dec-20               'http://go.microsoft'
```

Above mentioned link is just for sample

I used the below code it showed all values under the status column as link. but I need only my report values as a link, not for text values

```
Function Myfunction 
{ 
    Import-CSV "my csv file link" |Select Name,Date,@{Label="Status";Expression={"<a href='$($_.Status)'>$($_.Status)</a>"}}|
    ConvertTo-Html 
} 
$html=Myfunction

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web 
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($html) | Out-File d:\temp\log.html
```

Used above code.it displayed all values in column status as link include pass, fail text too.
So I need only if it's mentioned as the text it will be text in the report. if its link needs as a link in the report too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to decide based on the name being "Report" then something like this should work.

```
Function Myfunction 
{
    $properties = 'Name',
                  'Date',
                  @{Label="Status";Expression={
                      $(if($_.name -eq 'Report'){"<a href='$($_.Status)'>$($_.Status)</a>"}else{$_.Status})
                  }}

    Import-CSV "my csv file link" | Select-Object $properties | ConvertTo-Html 
}
```

If you want to only add link if the value is like a URL, then you could do something like this instead.

```
Function Myfunction 
{
    $properties = 'Name',
                  'Date',
                  @{Label="Status";Expression={
                      $(if($_.status -match '://'){"<a href='$($_.Status)'>$($_.Status)</a>"}else{$_.Status})
                  }}

    Import-CSV "my csv file link" | Select-Object $properties | ConvertTo-Html 
}
```